# Fixing ArcScene Menubar that disappeared?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene

My ArcScene menubar is disappeared. I am trying multiple time to fix it but failed.

Can anyone help me to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your symptoms suggest that returning ArcScene to its factory settings may be worth considering.  To reset ArcScene you can delete or rename your Normal.sxt (in a similar fashion to how you may reset ArcMap via its Normal.mxt).

The Online Help page entitled [About configuring the user interface](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/get-started/customizing-the-ui/about-configuring-the-user-interface.htm) describes where to find these templates:

> The Normal templates—Normal.mxt (ArcMap), Normal.gxt (ArcCatalog),
>   Normal.3dt (ArcGlobe), and Normal.sxt (ArcScene)—are located in your
>   user settings folder. For example, in Windows 2000 or XP, the ArcMap
>   Normal.mxt can be found in C:\Documents and
>   Settings\\Application Data\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcMap\Templates,
>   and in Windows Vista, it can be found in
>   C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcMap\Templates.